# How to track time spent by a task before getting cancelled

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am doing a

```
Task.Delay(durationInMilliseconds, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(taskResult =>{
    if (!taskResult.IsCanceled && taskResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if (taskResult.IsCanceled)
    {
        //persist the time spent before task got cancelled
    }
});
```

How can I track the duration for which the task ran before it got cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx). It contains a high resolution timer. Start the timer whenever the tasks starts, when you want to check the elapsed time, call one if it's properties.

## How to use:

`Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();`

`long elapsedMillis = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;`